# TypeScript error - property component does not exist on React mui MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using [react mui MenuItem](https://v4-7-2.material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) and I need to make a menu item as a link. I have tried to that like this:

```
        <MenuItem
          component={<Link href={`/backend/api/exam/${row.id}/result`} />}
          className={classes.menuItem}
          onClick={() => handleClose()}>
          Result
        </MenuItem>
```

But, when I do that, it throws an error where it says that property `component` does not exist on `MenuItem`:

> Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {
> action?: ((instance: ButtonBaseActions | null) => void) |
> RefObject | null | undefined; buttonRef?:
> ((instance: unknown) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined;
> ... 7 more ...; TouchRippleProps?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & {
> ...; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...>...'.  TS2322

What am I doing wrong here, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation:

> **Type:** elementType
>
> **Description:** Either a string to use a DOM element or a component.

Using a component as a `React.Node` wouldn't work.

The component prop expects the following: `React.Element<typeof Component>`.

In your case, providing the component as a `typeof` will do the trick:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
....

<MenuItem
  component={Link}
  to={`/backend/api/exam/${row.id}/result`}
  className={classes.menuItem}
  onClick={() => handleClose()}>
  Result
</MenuItem>
```

Another work around would be to wrap your `<MenuItem>` inside a `<Link>`:

```
<Link to={`/backend/api/exam/${row.id}/result`}>
  <MenuItem
    className={classes.menuItem}
    onClick={() => handleClose()}>
  >
    Result
  </MenuItem>
</Link>
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the difference of using component like you did and using the actual component?

Comment: You are passing a `React.Node` to the prop but the component prop is expecting a type of  `elementType` and not a `React.Node`, so all this prop is expecting from you is to give a type of what your `React.Node` should be. Which is basically the same as doing the following: `React.Element<typeof Link>`, but you only need to provide the component name instead of the whole line. I would refer to this for more information: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-element